# Why repeat birkas hamazon after omitting "yaale v'yavo" on chol hamoed

Tags: shabbat, mistakes, bentching, rosh-chodesh-new-month, chol-hamoed

*Aruch Hashulchan*, [*OC* 188](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%A4%D7%97):18, cites a difference of opinion regarding the following case. On *Shabas* which is *rosh chodesh*, someone says the *Shabas* addition in *birkas hamazon* (grace after the meal) but omits the *rosh chodesh* addition. (The case is actually more closely circumscribed than that; see e.g. :20.) Some say he must repeat *birkas hamazon* because he was required to eat and thus say *birkas hamazon*, which he didn't do properly, and others says he need not and thus must not repeat *birkas hamazon* because his requirement to eat didn't stem from its being *rosh chodesh*. Because of the difference of opinion, the *Aruch Hashulchan* concludes: "a doubt about benedictions — be lenient" and don't repeat *birkas hamazon*.

Yet, in [490](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A6):2 and :5, he says as follows: Someone who omits the *chol hamoed* addition to *birkas hamazon* should not repeat *birkas hamazon*; and, on *Shabas* which is *chol hamoed*, someone who omits the *chol hamoed* addition but says the *Shabas* addition should repeat *birkas hamazon*.

Why is that latter case different from the *rosh chodesh* case? It would seem to be subject to the same difference of opinion and one should therefore not repeat *birkas hamazon*.

Comment: Maybe it's because the normal chiyuv to eat of Shabbos is also "enhanced" by the moed.  Either you're eating matza or you're eating in the sukkah.  A nafka mina would be for women on Sukkos (or for men if it's raining).

Comment: Normal halacha is not as the Oruch Hashulchan. But I cannot find any evidence that the OH holds that a bread meal is obligatory on Chol Hamoed.

Answer (score 1):

See Magen Avraham siman 505 sk 1:

> ובמשנ' רפ"ד דסוכ' אמרי' ההלל והשמחה ח' ימים וע"ש ובסי' קפ"ח ס"ז משמע דדי באכיל' פירות ומ"מ נ"ל לכתחל' מצוה לאכול פת עיין סי' תרס"ד:‏
>
> In Mishna at the begining of the first chapter of Succa, they say that the simcha continues 8 days. But the Shulchan Aruch in 188, 7 states that to eat fruits (without bread) is enough. But I (the Magen Avraham) think that lechatechilla there is a mitsva to eat bread (not equivalent to Rosh Chodesh). The Magen Avraham seems to say that this is a machloket rishonim {and BY says cites SMG and Kol Bo against RMBM and Rabenu Yerucham and the SA stated as Rambam that fruits mealvis enough} if chol hamoed is equivalent to Rosh Chodesh.

Bet Yosef 188:

> ואם חל  **ר"ח בשבת והזכיר של שבת ולא של ר"ח היה אומר ה"ר יוסף שאין מחזירין** וכו' כ"כ המרדכי שם ובהגהות מרדכי פ"ב דשבת כ' שתי הסברות  **ודעת הרשב"א בפרק שלשה שאכלו כדעת ה"ר יחיאל דכיון דע"כ אכיל אפי' טעה בשל ר"ח מחזירין אותו**: ב"ה ולענין הלכה נקטינן כה"ר יוסף דספק ברכות להקל:‏
>
> There is an additional machloket, when R. Chodesh (or chol hamoed according to Rambam) falls on Shabbat, a first opinion says that since the meal is required in Shabbat, so each details of the bentsh is a part of the duty (if yaale veyavo of rosh chodesh was not mentioned, we have to bless a second time )and a second opinion says that the shabbat's mention is required, not Rosh Chodesh's. Bet Yosef stated as the last opinion by doubt.

Aruch Hadhulchan 490, 2:

> וכן מזכירו בברכת המזון. ואם לא אמרו – אין מחזירין אותו, מפני שאינו חובה לאכול פת.‏

AH 490, 5:

> ואם לא אמר – מחזירין אותו. וכן בברכת המזון, מפני שבשבת חובה לאכול פת.‏

It seems that the Aruch Hashulchan makes a combination. He follows in conclusion the first opinion quoted on Bet Yosef 188 (Kol Bo and Smag) in cases in which we can combinate the Rashba and Rabenu Yechiel.

Comment: Clearer now. Thanks. Also it seems plausible.